# How to convert tags in all tags in xml to lowercase without changing case of atribute values?

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I've inherited some xml files which has all tags in uppercase. I would like to convert them to lowercase using either a regular expression or via XSLT. It would be handy to be able to know both ways. Unfortunately, I find regex and XSLT syntax baffling at times, but I'm working on it. :)

(Edit: added following contrived example)

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NOVEL TITLE="Now That's A Novel Title" AUTHOR="Harry Handelbar">
  <PREFACE>  <!-- XHTML FORMATTED TEXT -->
    <P>It would be remiss of me to neglect to thank the bottle.</P>
  </PREFACE>
  <CHAPTER TITLE="" TYPE="NUM">
    <PROLOGUE>Success, like death, marks the end of... </PROLOGUE>
      <MAINTEXT> <!-- XHTML FORMATTED TEXT -->
      <P>It seems a violent betrayal, me divulging how...</P>
      <P>The years had not been kind Felix Lake. His constant...</P>
    </MAINTEXT>
  </CHAPTER>
  <CHAPTER TITLE="" TYPE="NUM">
  <MAINTEXT> <!-- XHTML FORMATTED TEXT -->
    <P>As luck would not have it, he did.</P>
    <!-- ECT ECT ECT -->
 </MAINTEXT>
  </CHAPTER>
</NOVEL>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<novel title="Now That's A Novel Title" author="Harry Handelbar">
  <preface>  <!-- XHTML FORMATTED TEXT -->
    <p>It would be remiss of me to neglect to thank the bottle.</p>
  </preface>
  <chapter title="" type="NUM">
    <prologue>Success, like death, marks the end of... </prologue>
      <maintext> <!-- XHTML FORMATTED TEXT -->
      <p>It seems a violent betrayal, me divulging how...</p>
      <p>The years had not been kind Felix Lake. His constant...</p>
    </maintext>
  </chapter>
  <chapter title="" type="NUM">
  <maintext> <!-- XHTML FORMATTED TEXT -->
    <p>As luck would not have it, he did.</p>
    <!-- ECT ECT ECT -->
 </maintext>
  </chapter>
</novel>
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: My bad on the P tags - after should be lowercase as well)

Comment: Can you post a sample XML, and desired output?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes to XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (untested):

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{lower-case(local-name())}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{lower-case(local-name())}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The **XSLT 1.0** version of the above would go like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), $uppercase, $lowercase)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{translate(local-name(), $uppercase, $lowercase)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this is assuming your element and attribute names do not contain upper-case characters other than the 26 explicitly listed (i.e. no Russian, Greek, diacritics, etc.).

Comment: This looks promising. It would appear that I am not using XSLT 2.0 though. (Got the " Could not find function: lower-case" message. Apparently Xalan (which I've used for years) is an XSLT 1.0 processor. I might have  look at an alternative. I use Apache FOP as well so I hope to find something compatible with that as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: @HarryHB Yes, there is no lower-case() function in XSLT 1.0. Which is why the alternative is clunky (see the edit above). Which is why I asked in the first place...

Comment: Top notch! The XSLT 1.0 version does the trick nicely. Yeah, sorry about the version confusion. I was labouring under a false assumption. 26 uppercase characters is enough for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to this regex:

```
<(\/?[a-zA-Z]*)\b.*?>
```

online tester:
http://regex101.com/#PCRE

Enjoy your code

Answer (score 0):

By using PHP you can do it like this...

```
<?php

$pattern= '/<\\w+|<\/\\w+/';
$fp = fopen("/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/test/test.xml", "r") or die("can't read stdin");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);
    $line = preg_replace_callback(
        $pattern,
        function ($matches) {
            return strtolower($matches[0]);
        },
        $line
    );
    echo htmlentities($line);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

It work fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might need 2 regexes in my opinion - one to convert the tag name, and another to convert the variable number of attribute-value pairs.

Here is how I could do it -

```
blah:tmp shreyas$ cat old.xml | perl -pe "s|(</?)([^> ]+)(.*?>)|\1\L\2\E\3|g" | perl -pe "s|(\w+)( ?= ?\".*?\")|\L\1\E\2|g" > processed.xml
blah:tmp shreyas$ diff new.xml processed.xml 
4c4
<     <P>It would be remiss of me to neglect to thank the bottle.</P>
---
>     <p>It would be remiss of me to neglect to thank the bottle.</p>
9,10c9,10
<       <P>It seems a violent betrayal, me divulging how...</P>
<       <P>The years had not been kind Felix Lake. His constant...</P>
---
>       <p>It seems a violent betrayal, me divulging how...</p>
>       <p>The years had not been kind Felix Lake. His constant...</p>
15c15
<     <P>As luck would not have it, he did.</P>
---
>     <p>As luck would not have it, he did.</p>
```

old.xml is your Before xml and new.xml is your After xml. processed.xml is the one generated by the command.

As you can see, the P tags in your after xml are still capital. I am not sure if they were typos or exceptions. I trreated them as typos since you mentioned changing all tags to small case.

With a small modification, you could run these commands on all of you inherited set of XMLs, and get them converted quickly.

Comment: The uppercase P tags were my bad (now edited out) - Luckily I have cygwin on my PC so I could try your method. Works fine, although it does leave the attribute names upper-cased. Can you suggest a mod.

Comment: @HarryHB if you are running this command - cat old.xml | perl -pe "s|(</?)([^> ]+)(.*?>)|\1\L\2\E\3|g" | perl -pe "s|(\w+)( ?= ?\".*?\")|\L\1\E\2|g" > processed.xml - in full, you shouldn't have any attribute names in upper case. In case somehow you are, then share that full node in the xml.